# How to capture multiple buttons under a single click function and send content to local storage

Tags: javascript, html

New to coding, 7 weeks into a Bootcamp class. I am trying to control 9 different buttons with a single click function in Javascript and I get an error message of ***"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"***. Each button should send textarea content to localStorage. As you can see from the HTML code, I am trying to control button "save9am" with the click at the top level with class "pageMaster". Help!

```js
var controlAll = document.querySelector("pageMaster");
controlAll.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = document.getElementById("box9").value;
        localStorage.setItem("text", clickedItem);
    }
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = document.getElementById("box16").value;
        localStorage.setItem("text", clickedItem);
    }

    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = document.getElementById("box17").value;
        localStorage.setItem("text", clickedItem);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```html
<tbody class="pageMaster">
    <tr>
      <div class = "col-md-2">
        <th scope="row" id="9amTime" class="timeOfDay">9:00am</th>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-8">
        <td class="event-box"><textarea class="text-box" value="" id="box9"></textarea></td>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2">
        <td class="save-box"><button id="save9am" class="btn btn-outline-secondary saveBtn" type="button"><i
          class="far fa-save"></i></button></td>
      </div>
    </tr>
<tbody>
```

Comment: controlAll is null because your querySelector should be `'.pageMaster'`. Period for selecting classes `.someClassName` and hash for ids `#someID`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked but now it is telling me, "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined". The "e" not defined is showing up at the end of the function after the last button when I callback the function, this is the end of the code:

Comment: You'll have to paste the code. The current code in your example isn't valid.

Comment: if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var clickedItem = document.getElementById("box17").value;
        localStorage.setItem("text", clickedItem);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
}
doSomething(e);

Comment: e should exist in this context. Try adding a reproducible example in your question with the code snippet tool.

Comment: Sorry for the messy code, the error is in the last (e), right after "doSomething".

Comment: in your example in that comment you're calling doSomething(e) manually, rather than having it called by the event listener. It's also still invalid code. You've two closing parenthesis and one opening. You should add it to a working snippet.

Comment: Just added the end portion of the code to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It's extremely difficult to read your question but I suspect this is what you *meant* to use:

```js
var container_elem = document.querySelector(".container");
container_elem.addEventListener("click", doSomething, false);

function doSomething(e) {
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
        var input_text = document.getElementById("textinput").value;
        console.log('input_text', input_text)
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<textarea id="textinput"></textarea>
<p>some arbitrary element</p>
<button>a buttin</button>
</div>
```

Comment: that is correct. I want "pageMaster" to recognize when any of the 9 buttons are clicked and send the content of "box#" to localStorage. Now the error is with the (e) at the end of the function when I recall the function.

Comment: Thought I needed to do it so it would complete the cycle through all 9 events.

Comment: I deleted the (e)doSomething and the error went away. Thank you very much.